# fill dropdown list with datasource inside jquery popup asp net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

so i have two dropdown lists that i am populating with data from datasource, i have breakpointed and seen that i get the data count i want, the problem is that i dont get them to show inside my popup.

i have used this code some else where and it works fine there, but not here for some reason.

ASPX:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_OnItemCommand" ID="rptList">
       <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlNodeClass" runat="server" ID="ddlNodeEdit" />
       <asp:DropDownList CssClass="ddlTranslatorClass" runat="server" ID="ddlTranslatorEdit" />
    </asp:Repeater>
```

C#:

```
        var nodes = _administrationSystem.GetNodes(); //This code works fine
        var translators = _phonesSystem.GetPhoneNumberTranslators();

        if (rptAdd.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            for (var count = 0; count < rptAdd.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                var ddlNode = (DropDownList)rptAdd.Items[count].FindControl("ddlNode");
                var ddlTranslator = (DropDownList)rptAdd.Items[count].FindControl("ddlTranslator");

                ddlNode.DataSource = nodes;
                ddlNode.DataTextField = "NodeName";
                ddlNode.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlNode.DataBind();

                ddlTranslator.DataSource = translators;
                ddlTranslator.DataTextField = "Description";
                ddlTranslator.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlTranslator.DataBind();
            }
        }

        if (rptList.Items.Count > 0) //This code does not work fine
        {
            for (var count = 0; count < rptList.Items.Count; count++)
            {
                var ddlNodeEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlNodeEdit");
                var ddlTranslatorEdit = (DropDownList)rptList.Items[count].FindControl("ddlTranslatorEdit");

                var getNode = _administrationSystem.GetNode(userId, ddlNodeEdit.SelectedIndex + 1);
                var getTranslator = _phonesSystem.GetPhoneNumberTranslator(Convert.ToInt32(ddlTranslatorEdit.SelectedValue));

                ddlNodeEdit.DataSource = getNode;
                ddlNodeEdit.DataTextField = "NodeName";
                ddlNodeEdit.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlNodeEdit.DataBind();

                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataSource = getTranslator;
                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataTextField = "Description";
                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddlTranslatorEdit.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: When are you doing all this? I mean your second block of code is inside which _event_?

Comment: Your code is true, and the problem is some where else that is not visible to us.